# Html button onclick redirection in .htaccess for wordpress sites

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a site with URL majorsolutionplatform.tech and I have already set up a temporal page for advert of my products with URL link (https://majorsolutionplatform.tech/dont-get-twisted/).

I want help to generate a redirect script that will direct every user that exits my site to this URL (https://majorsolutionplatform.tech/dont-get-twisted/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no unobtrusive way that you can control user flow, that said there is a JavaScript script which can help, this needs to be included in every page (global.js maybe)

```
// code here
  window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    window.open(‘https://majorsolutionplatform.tech/dont-get-twisted/’, 400, 800);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks Wandawi, i will appreciate if you can expand further. Where do i need to place this codes on my wordpress site? And again, i will appreciate if you can write a code with the above url that will help direct my users to the created advart page. i provide free contents, with a few paid files, i don't mind you help on this.

Comment: I don’t think you should expect full solutions, do little research and understand the implications.

Comment: This might help on where you should place the script (after editing it) https://www.godaddy.com/garage/3-ways-to-insert-javascript-into-wordpress-pages-or-posts/

Comment: This is the page i want every user who exits my site to be pointed to: {https://majorsolutionplatform.tech/dont-get-twisted/}

Comment: Thanks so much, i have actually done so research before heading over to Stackoverflow, and i am sure, this is the last bus stop to my question.

Comment: You can use some plugin to add JS to your site (if you don't know how to use FTP) and add this code in it. FYI, replace the ' '